# DLNA through two routers?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, dlna

I have been trying to achieve a DLNA / Media Share between my Nexus 5 and Xbox 360, so far I have been unable to achieve this and I decided to turn here to see if anyone could shed some light.

What I basically want to do is stream media **from my Nexus 5 to my Xbox 360**, now what makes this all quite confusing is I have a standalone router flashed with DD-WRT to handle connections upstairs, this includes the Xbox 360. The app I am using to try and achieve this is **BubbleUPnP Pro**.

The Xbox 360 has its own IP Address defined within the second router, I guess it is an Access Point as it simply connects to the main router wirelessly and then provides access through the ethernet ports.

My question is, is it possible for me to stream media from my Nexus 5 (which is connected to the Main Router) through the Access Point and to my Xbox 360? If so - will it require any action on the Main Router and what are the steps I need to take to achieve it?

Thank you -

(I have attached a image to document how everything is set up network-wise)
[image: Two routers DNLA layout]

Answer (score 2):

That's not really an Android question, but rather network related. But the short answer is:

**It should work as long as all the devices described share the same "subnet".**

I have a comparable setup here (TV→cable→router→cable→main-router→wireless→tablet), and can use BubbleUPnP fine to stream from my tablet to my PC. All share the same network (`192.168.1.*`, netmask `255.255.255.0`), so UPnP/DLNA finds it's way from end to end. The main router acts as DHCP server for all devices in the network, no other DHCP server concurring.

If however your main router and router2 both use their own subnets, that might get tricky.